# CCLabelAtlas StartCharMap:':'

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I want to make timer string with CCLabelAtlas. The problem is the character, ":". I had added this character in .png file as ":/0123456789". I can see only ":" and can not see any numbers for timer.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK, cocos2d use startCharacter property to calculate needed symbol position according to ASCII table. For example, the next character in ASCII after ':' is ';', not '/'. Place your characters as they are placed in ASCII and it should be shown fine. The right order is

```
/0123456789:
```

of course, start character in this case will be '/', not ':'

Comment: That's what I was going to say. This ASCII table website has helped me a couple times: http://www.asciitable.com/